# jest testing with es6 + jspm + systemjs + reactJS

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs, jspm, systemjs

I'm trying to figure out how to make my unit tests in my reactJS ES6 application. My application is already using es6 module system, transpiled with jspm/babel to systemJs.

I found babel-jest as preprocessor but even with it, I can't run my tests because jest can't find SystemJs. (**"System is not defined"** error is shown in the console)

In the browser, as explained in jspm documentation, SystemJs is loaded globally. I guess I should load SystemJs inside my preprocessor, but How can I make systemJs available for loading additional modules in my tests?

Thanks in advance

Comment: PS. I'm trying to understand how to make it work, so if I am doing domething wrong, please, tell me what!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I'm not using jest anymore. Switched over to simple jasmine. With Jasmine, karma, jspm karma plugin, I can run unit tests, I still have some troubles when I want to mock dependencies, but I think I should study systemjs a little more and I should manage to do it, when I have time...

Comment: There's this: https://github.com/shidhincr/react-jest-gulp-jspm-seed

Comment: @ShawnErquhart, that example only works because [`require`](https://github.com/shidhincr/react-jest-gulp-jspm-seed/blob/master/scripts/testComponent.js#L3) is being used. Unfortunately, Jest doesn't support the mocking of ES6 style `import`s at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Jest does not support SystemJS ES6 modules at the moment.

See the following comments:

> So it sounds like jest assumes that your modules resolve based on the Node resolution algorithm.
>
> Unfortunately this isn't compatible with SystemJS's resolution algorithm.
>
> If there was a way in jest to set a "custom resolver" algorithm through an API then we could plug jspm into jest, but I'm not sure if this is currently possible.
>
> -- [Comment by Guy Bedford](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/552#issuecomment-116785713), creator of SystemJS, Jun 2015

---

> It is unlikely there'll be official support for [SystemJS] unless it is a community contribution.
>
> -- [Comment by @cpojer](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/367#issuecomment-171708621), Jest Collaborator, Jan 2016

---

Also see the following issue: [Invalid URL is thrown when requiring systemjs in jest test cases](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/840)

Comment: Yeah - cpojer's comment that you linked there was actually a part of a quick exchange between he and I in my quest to make Jest and jspm work. I think we'll see a solution in the next six months as jspm/systemjs adoption picks up pace.

Comment: Ah I see now, thanks @ShawnErquhart. Let's hope you're right! Is the six months your gut feeling or did I miss some information?

Comment: Pure gut. Maybe a better way to phrase it: I'd be surprised if there wasn't a standard, albeit basic, jspm/Jest setup available by summer.

Answer (score 0):

in essence to get Jest to play nice with an app running on JSPM/SystemJS you need to "teach" it about all the mapping it holds in the config.js file (or however you call System.config())

the **long answer** is that you need to create an entry for each dependency you have installed with JSPM like this:

```
//jest configuration 
moduleNameMapper: {     
   ...
   "^redux$": "redux@3.6.0",
   ...
}
```

for each alias you have, you need at least one entry:

```
moduleNameMapper: {     
        ...
        "^common\\/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/common/$1", //for a dir alias
       "^actions$": "<rootDir>/src/actions/index", //for a file alias
       ...
}
```

you also need to have these mappings in your *nodeNameMapper*:

```
moduleNameMapper: {     
    ...
         "^npm:(.*)": "<rootDir>/jspm_packages/npm/$1",
            "^github:(.*)": "<rootDir>/jspm_packages/github/$1",
    ...
}
```

and finally, you need to have this *moduleDirectories* config:

```
moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "jspm_packages/npm", "jspm_packages/github"]
```

this isnt really practical because you dont want to keep two copies of all your dependencies registry and have to sync them when they change...

so the **short** and **better** answer, you use my [gulp-jest-jspm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jest-jspm) plugin :)

even if you dont use gulp, you can use its *getJestConfig()* method to generate the config for you before you run Jest.