# React JSPM testing framework

Tags: testing, reactjs, jspm

What is the best testing framework and its associated helper libraries to use for a project in React and JSPM? I'm looking for various libraries combined together and what is specific to that set which makes it a powerful toolset? (Looking to incorporate redux later on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently build testing environment for a react application using JSPM.

I first wanted to use *Jest*, as it is recommended by the community with react. But then I found out [that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945193/jest-testing-with-es6-jspm-systemjs-reactjs), saying support for JSPM/SystemJs wasn't on the roadmap at the moment.

Although it exists some work to make it work, see for example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/systemjs-jest

---

Then I chose to use **Jasmine** as it is quite known in my company, and I already worked with it.
Also I think *Jest* used to be based on *Jasmine*, so many react-specific matchers developed for *Jest* are also compatible with *Jasmine*.

---

So I ended up using **Jasmine** with **Karma**, using **karma-jasmine** and [karma-uiuxengineering-jspm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-uiuxengineering-jspm).

Make sure to read the documentation of **karma-uiuxengineering-jspm** thoroughly, it took me some time to set the environment up.

Some nice additions:
 - *jasmine-enzyme* (installed with JSPM)
 - *karma-mocha-reporter* (installed with npm)
 - *karma-phantomjs-launcher* (installed with npm)