# loading local modules in JEST with JSPM

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, systemjs, jspm

I'm trying to use jest in my JSPM project.

My jspm.config file looks like this:

```
SystemJS.config({
  paths: {
      "npm:": "jspm_packages/npm/",
      "github:": "jspm_packages/github/",
      "moment": "scripts/vendor/moment/moment.min.js"
  }
});
```

In my package.json i have the follow JEST configurations:

```
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^npm:(.*)": "<rootDir>/jspm_packages/npm/$1",
      "^github:(.*)": "<rootDir>/jspm_packages/github/$1",
      "moment": "<rootDir>/public/scripts/vendor/moment"
    },
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "jspm_packages/npm",
      "jspm_packages/github",
      "public/scripts/vendor",
      "node_modules"
    ],
  "rootDir": "",
  "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
    "jspm_packages/npm/js-tokens@1.0.3/"
  ]
},
```

I try the aproach of the poeticGeek answer  in [jest testing with es6 + jspm + systemjs + reactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945193/jest-testing-with-es6-jspm-systemjs-reactjs)

but in my test.js whenever i `import moment from 'moment';` the tests never completes, seems to enter in an infinite loop.

If i remove the moment inside the moduleNameMapper appears the following error: `Cannot find module 'moment' from 'date.test.js'`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was:`"rootDir": ""` in the configuration file.